# Как писать числа дробью?

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа, модули

Как написать числа не так: 2 / 1, а так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятно что вы имеете вииду. "Написать" куда?

Comment: В Вывод, ну я то пишу на KivyMD но даже если подскажете как сделать с print() то сойдет

Comment: `print(' 1\n---\n 2')`

Comment: Нет, я так для показа написал три"-", должна бить одна длинная

Comment: Вот я исправил изображение

Comment: Вам нужно именно такое отображение чисел при печати или средства для работы с дробями?

Comment: Отображение, с вторым я так справлюсь

Comment: @Arteman `print('1\n─\n2')`

Comment: Спасибо,но для этого нет какого либо модуля чтобы виглядело красивее?

Comment: @Arteman для работы с дробями `fractions`, для отображения в консоли -- вряд ли. Для отображения в GUI наверняка есть, но KivyMD не знаю

Comment: Понятно, Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В юникоде есть функционал для того, чтобы обозначить, что речь идёт именно о дроби. Но как именно это будет выглядеть - зависит от шрифта. Это может быть как такое же написание "число под числом", как в вашем вопросе, так и написание через косую черту двух чисел, одно из которых чуть выше, а другое чуть ниже.

Например, вот такой код:

```
print(u'\u00bd')
```

выведет дробь ½ (в большинстве современных шрифтов будет выглядеть именно так)

Для нескольких наиболее распространённых дробей есть отдельные символы юникода. Для остальных дробей можно использовать символ fraction slash, поставив его между двумя любыми целыми числами:

```
print(u'{}\u2044{}'.format(5, 6))
```

Но эта возможность шрифтами поддерживается хуже всего. В моём терминале, например, этот код выводит просто `5/6`. Но, возможно, вам удастся найти шрифт, который будет выводить этот символ так, как вы хотите.

Подробнее про дроби в Юникоде: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дроби_в_Юникоде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda fraction: f'\n---\n'.join(fraction.strip().replace(' ', '').split('/'))
```